# Upload file chunks into MongoDb using mgo/golang

Tags: file, go, gridfs, mgo

In my case I have a logic which should upload large chunked files for example if I have a file which size is 10mb , I need to send PUT request with 1mb file chunks , 10 times, but the mgo ([mgo.v2](https://gopkg.in/mgo.v2)) is not allow to open file for writing

```
    func UploadFileChunk(rw http.ResponseWriter,rq *http.Request) {


    fileid:= mux.Vars(rq)["fileid"]

    rq.ParseMultipartForm(10000)
    formFile:=rq.MultipartForm.File["file"]

    content,err:= formFile[0].Open()

    defer content.Close()


    if err != nil {
        http.Error(rw,err.Error(),http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    file,err:= db.GridFS("fs").OpenId(bson.ObjectIdHex(fileid))

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(rw,err.Error(),http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    data,err := ioutil.ReadAll(content)

    n,_:= file.Write(data)



    file.Close()
    // Write a log type message
    fmt.Printf("%d bytes written to the Mongodb instance\n", n)
}
```

So I want to every time write a new chunk but 1) The mgo not allows to open file for writing 2) I don't know is this way a good?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending chunked files to save in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415962/sending-chunked-files-to-save-in-mongodb)

Comment: Please do not double post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415962/sending-chunked-files-to-save-in-mongodb and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368658/golang-update-existing-file-in-mongodb