# Golang update existing file in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, file, go

I have created api which receive and save files into mongodb,My api based on golang and using mgo to work with mongodb, So mgo documentation says that the files which already exists can not be update, but in my app there is a function which receive a chunked files and should write on file.
I have googled and have not found any solution, some links or articles will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you saw that in the mgo documentation but you can absolutely update documents in Mongo using mgo, as evidenced by the [mgo documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Update), particularly the functions `Update`, `UpdateId`, `UpdateAll`, `Upsert`, and `UpsertId`.